# Assert Commits are in a Release Branch

Tags: android, github, build

Is there a way / tool for ensuring a list of commits are in a branch / release ? or to ensure hotfixes get merged back in to master?

Trying to find an efficient / automated way to create a release where I can ensure master has the last release / hotfix included as well as a list of relevant commits.

any recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log` for that task.

See the part "Revision selection" it in the Git Book, specifically ["Commit ranges"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_commit_ranges). You can make `git log` only show you the commits in `hotfix` branch which are not reachable from the `release` branch:

```sh
$ git log 

* ce05a4f add 6 (HEAD -> release)
*   23775d3 Merge branch 'hotfix'
|\  
| | * 576d0c3 add 5 (hotfix)
| |/  
| * deceb3f add 4
|/  
* a5887d8 add 3
* 82ff96d add 2
* c6c4285 add 1
* 5d7fdb3 initial commit

$  git lg master..hotfix
* 576d0c3 add 5 (hotfix)
```

Now you see the commits from `hotfix` that have not been included in the `release` branch thus far.

If you want to wrap that in a script or hook you could only allow a release if the output is empty (i.e. all hotfix commits are included, nothing remains unmerged).